# Problem in converting .htaccess mod_rewrite to nginx directive

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I have great difficulties converting this apache rewrite rule to nginx:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

What I've tried
**A:**

```
 location  / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

**B:**

```
 location  / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.phps$args;
    }
```

However A does give 404 error for any `/path` and B works for `/path/to/somewhere` but does downloads `/path`.

here is my complete vhost:

```
server {
        listen 8000;
        root /var/www/myphpapp;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name localhost;
        #autoindex off;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ index.php$is_args$args; #A
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; #B

        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

So I'm wondering what is the correct nginx directive?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo. You missed a slash:

```
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Comment: Well when I use `/index.php$is_args$args` it just downloads `index.php` when I visit `/signup` page

Comment: That means, nginx forwarded the request to index.php, but it doesn't know how to execute the file. So now the problem is in php setup. can you share more info about your setup ?